# How does postgresql Date relate java Date?

Tags: java, postgresql, timestamp

I am working on a project that requires to get the time when a new customer creates his account, and then keep that time in the database for later use. However, I dont really understand the postgresql's timestamp data type? Is it a String a Calendar or Date object relative to java (may you give me an insert and retrieved example)?

Comment: Becareful, `Timestamp` is not the same as a `Date`, `Timestamp` contains both date and time information where as `Date` contains only date information, as far as PosgreSQL is concerned.  `Timestamp`.  As far as I can recall, a pg `Timestamp` should map to `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: Thank you. That is my concern.

Answer (score 1):

As @MadProgrammer mentions, `Timestamp` and `Date` are different in both *Java* and *Postgres*. While one could use `java.sql.Timestamp`, I generally represent my *Postgres* `timestamp`s in *POJOs* as `String`s instead.

The reason for this is that it eliminates a lot of the potential headaches associated with *timestamps* (timezones, different formats, etc.), as one can simply use a *Postgres* text representation of a `timestamp`, and it can still be passed back and forth with *Postgres*. The exception to this rule would be if you really need it to truly be a `Timestamp` on the *Java* end because, say, you're *ETL*'ing it outside of *Postgres* to some other platform, and so can't rely on the *Postgres* text representation the way you could if you were getting data out of *Postgres* and putting it back into *Postgres*.

Let's say you had a timestamp that was `2014-08-08 02:11:21.215428`, and a table like this:

```
create table foo
(
  id serial,
  created timestamp without time zone default now(),
  notes text
);
```

You could represent that in a *POJO* like this:

```
class FooBean
{
    int id;
    String created;
    String notes;
};
```

The key to keep in mind then is if you go to use that value back in another query, you need to *cast* it back to a `timestamp` (i.e. `notes::timestamp`), or else *Postgres* will throw a cast exception.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

This method helps to obscure timezone-related headaches also. Timezones can be represented textually as well, simply by a `-XX` expression on the string. For example, the timezone-less string `2014-08-08 02:11:21.215428` could represent a timezone via the string `2014-08-08 02:11:21.215428-04`.

As @MadProgrammer mentioned in a comment below, *Postgres* also has a timestamp type with timezones; I just happened to choose ones without for the above example.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I am also thinking to represent it as a String. However, I dont really have solid idea how to deal with different timezones so that I think postgresql Timestamp will save some extra steps.

Comment: @user3819470 If you need to manage time zones, postgresql has a `TimeStamp` with timezone type...You could always maintain the data without time zone information to start with and convert it to local time (with time zone) once you have it in your program, but it all comes down to context